# Login Script Redirecting me back to login page

Tags: php, html

I have a login form that requires a username and password. It does tell you when your username and password is wrong but when its correct it just takes you back to login. I have tried everything but the only thing that works is to remove the checklogin.php but then it removes the point of having a login page

Below are my Check Login and Login page scripts:

CHECKLOGIN.PHP

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['finance_id']))
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="login.php"; </script>';


?>
```

LOGIN.PHP

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<?php
include("php/dbconnect.php");
include("php/checklogin.php");
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{

$username =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['username']));
$password =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

if($username=='' || $password=='')
{
$error='All fields are required';
}

$sql = "select * from Finance where username='".$username."' and password = '".md5($password)."'";

$q = $conn->query($sql);
if($q->num_rows==1)
{
$res = $q->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['finance_username']=$res['username'];
$_SESSION['finance_id']=$res['id'];
$_SESSION['finance_name']=$res['name'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="FinanceManage.php"; 
</script>';

}else
{
 $error = 'Invalid Username or Password';
}

}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>iBroker Systems</title>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<style>
.myhead{
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
text-align:center;
}
</style>

</head>
<body >
 <div class="container">

     <div class="row ">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

                        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; margin-top:50px; border:solid 3px #0e0e0e;">
                          <h3 class="myhead">iBroker Systems</h3>
                          <center><img src="img/logo.png"></center>
                            <form role="form" action="login.php" method="post">
                                <hr />
                                <?php
                                if($error!='')
                                {                                   
                                echo '<h5 class="text-danger text-center">'.$error.'</h5>';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <h3 class="myhead">Finance Administration</h3>

                                 <div class="form-group input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-tag"  ></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Username " name="username" required />
                                    </div>

                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"  ></i></span>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Your Password" name="password" required />
                                    </div>



                                 <center><button class="btn btn-primary" type= "submit" name="login">Login Now</button>
                               </center>
                                </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are not initialized in PHP if `session_start()` is not called, put it in the very beginning of all your scripts

Another thing, for redirection, you better use `header('Location: login.php');die();`

Comment: I have 2 logins screens for different sections of the program. The first one works fine. Why would this one not?

Comment: It is redirecting but as soon as it opens the php file i direct it to, Checklogin.php sends it back to login screen